# Convexity function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve that this function is convex, but, I'm still stuck with it.

If there is a function $f(x,y) = x^xy^y$, where $x,y > 0$, how could I prove that this function is convex?

My thought : I think that it is impossible to use the definition directly. Instead, even though we can use the hessian matrix (i,e, if I prove its hessian matrix is positive definite or positive semidefinite, we are done), I'm still don't know.

Comment: $f(x,y)=e^{g(x,y)}$ with $g(x,y)=x\ln(x)+y\ln(y)$. First show that $g$ is convex. Since $f$ is an increasing and convex function of $g$, $f$ must also be convex.

Comment: I see. Thanks.!